# LLVM MDNode inheritence

Tags: c++, inheritance, llvm

I need to create a `DIVariable` from an existing `MDNode`.

According to the [documentation](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DIVariable.html), `DIVariable` inherits from `MDNode`. But directly attempting to create gives the error:

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'llvm::DIVariable'
                  DIVariable newDIVar(*newMDNode);
                             ^        ~~~~~~~~~~
/root/llvm-7.0.0/include/llvm/IR/DebugInfoMetadata.h:2193:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'llvm::MDNode' to 'const llvm::DIVariable' for 1st
      argument
class DIVariable : public DINode {
```

I tried going one level further and creating a `DINode` from the `MDNode` to see if that works, which gives a similar error:

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'llvm::DINode'
                  DINode newDINode(*newMDNode);
                         ^         ~~~~~~~~~~
/root/llvm-7.0.0/include/llvm/IR/DebugInfoMetadata.h:155:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'llvm::MDNode' to 'const llvm::DINode' for 1st
      argument
class DINode : public MDNode {
```

That error doesnt make sense to me. How does a class that inherits from another not convert to it implicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer for anyone searching in the future.

[In r234255](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=234255) many implicit copy constructors were removed in favor of [cast<>, isa<>, and dyn_cast<>](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-isa-cast-and-dyn-cast-templates).